# Editing bitcoinJ for Android Altcoin App

Tags: wallet, bitcoinj, android

So there is an altcoin created by another party and i want to edit the bitcoin-wallet app for android so that it connects to the new network.

Is it enough to edit core/params/MainNetParams.java in order for the core functionalities of the app to work?

Thanks in advance!